# Arduino/Genuino 101 - EOL / Junk the board(s)?

Tags: 101

https://hackaday.com/2017/07/25/the-end-of-arduino-101-intel-leaves-maker-market/
https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/25832/Arduino-101-Firmware-Package-1-0
https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Makers/Intel-Curie-End-of-Life-Scheduled/td-p/397068?profile.language=en

Intel EOL'd the Arduino/Genuino 101 board.  The *end* is so complete that you cannot download the drivers using the **Board Manager**.

To make matters worse, my old Ubuntu machine, with an old Arduino IDE, is unable to upload to my existing 101 boards (*PRESS MASTER RESET* error).

1. Should I *junk* these boards?
2. Is there a 3rd party site that is hosting the drivers?

Comment: Arduino's brief partnership with Intel was an abortion that should never have happened. Junk the boards and use something sensible.

Comment: Ugh... hate throwing electronics in the trash almost as much as I hate wasting my time on a dead end.

Comment: You could always put it on eBay for some other sucker to be disappointed with...

Comment: Maybe one day it'll be a collectors' item and be worth millions ;)

Comment: This raises the obvious question:  *How does one determine which Arduino flavor will be supported in the future?*  I don't need things to last forever, but this is one of the few pieces of electronics I need to throw into the junk heap.

Comment: You can pretty much guarantee that the AVR based ones will last for the foreseeable future. ARM ones will probably change rapidly. Anything form third parties, like Intel, or any of the million-and-one ARM boards there are now, well, it's anyone's guess. The manufacturer will always support the chip for as long as they are making it. Whether you have the tools to work with that chip without the Arduino framework though is down to your abilities. You can probably still use the 101 just not with Ardiuno, and using a proper programmer (JTAG?)

Comment: I've heard of JTAG, but never used it.  I thought JTAG was a hardware (almost cable) standard.  What is the IDE?

Comment: I'm getting the picture from:  https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/arm-programming/all and https://www.instructables.com/id/JTAG-ICE-With-Arduino-IDE/ .  However, doesn't Atmel Studio need to know something about the Intel 101 to compile for it?